# Redirect to login is always triggered because there is a delay from useContext()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to return the user to login if he is not authenticated. Right now it is always triggered when I use this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      router.push('/login')
    }
  }, [])
```

The user comes from a context provider I set up at my _app.js. I fetch the user using this:

```
const { user, userDetails } = useContext(UserContext);
```

But because there is a delay somehow in fetching it always returns me to login, even when I am authenticated and there is a user.

UserContext.Provider:

```
<UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: user,
        handleLogout: handleLogout,
        userDetails: userDetails,
      }}
    >
<Component {...pageProps} />
</UserContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is a boolean you can set it as null

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


useEffect(()=> {
  //--> fetch user and set it true o false
 
}, []);
```

then:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === false) {
      router.push('/login')
    }
  }, [user])
```

Comment: Sorry, but that won't work. Because you'll get a `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` Fetching from `useContext()` doesn't work in a `useEffect()`.

Comment: This is an example, I don't know how are you implementing this, the idea is set user to null, once you get if user is logged or not, you will check if user is false, this way user===false, not this if(!user).

Comment: Thanks! You helped me in the right direction. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to @lissettdm.

I added in `_app.js` a new value

```
 const [checkUser, setCheckUser] = useState(null);
<UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: user,
        handleLogout: handleLogout,
        userDetails: userDetails,
        checkUser: checkUser,
      }}
    >
```

Then I import it and check using useEffect:

```
const { user, userDetails, checkUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkUser === false) {
      router.push("/account");
    }
  }, [checkUser]);
```